# Why can't I access params within resolve?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a show page and I want to make sure the data is available before i display this page. It was my understanding that using the resolve property in a route was the best way to do this. However with ui-router i Don't have access to attributes in $state.params. Is there any way around this or am I supposed to just query for the object in the controller? I made a simple plunkr to demonstrate the problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/cSgExy7QOpjx7jEEV7v0?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, you should be referencing `$stateParams` in your resolve, not `$state.params`. Also, the Plunkr was broken because you were injecting a service (`Tournament`) that you didn't include in your excerpt. This works fine:

```
resolve: { 
  tournament:  function($stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams)  // Prints { tournament_id: 1 }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the param object doesn't populate fast enough.

If you wrap the alert in the resolve function with a timeout of 0 milliseconds it seems to work.

I don't have any experience with angular ui router but I assume it is related to the digest cycle still processing and the timeout forces the alert to wait until the digest cycle is complete.

Comment: The problem with that is the controller instantiates before the the $timeout is run so it would be faster to just do the query in the controller. The point of using resolve is to make sure I have the data i need before the controller is instantiated.